# How testng.xml redo for junit 5

Tags: junit, testng

I am currently transferring the project from testNG to junit 5 and I have a problem with the replacement testng.xml to a similar implementation on junit 5. I'm new to this, so I can't figure it out yet. during test execution, the testng org.testng.internal classes are accessed and then the file is accessed testng.xml. Is there an alternative to this in junit 5 ? I am grateful in advance to all those who answered.

Comment: There is no similar implementation of suites in Junit 5. https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/744 .  You can go through https://www.journaldev.com/21768/junit-vs-testng

Answer (score 0):

There's no strict equivalent in JUnit5. As far as I'm aware, the `test.xml` file is used to define a set of suites for TestNG. You can do the same in JUnit5 with help of the following annotations: @SelectPackages and @SelectClasses.

```java
@RunWith(JUnit.class)
@SelectPackages(
{ "com.example.package1", "org.suite.package2" })
public class JUnit5TestSuite {
}
```